# Tileserver in 2012 r2

Tags: openstreetmap, tile-server, windows-server-2012

Last week I tried everything to build up a tile server but the Tile Server I was using (tileserver-gl) doesn't work for the 2012 r2 WS Server.

After that i tried it with leaflet but I couldn't figure it out. And I also tried it with docker but docker requires the WS Server 2016.

I need a tileserver there you can edit the style and using your own .osm, where the map is stored in. What i tried: tileserver-gl, leaflet (can't use my own style and map), brouter, mapbox, mapnik.

**How can I edit the style from the map so that I can make the water red or green?**

I need a tileserver using my own .osm files and also to configure my own style.

Comment: Does it need to be Windows? If not, read https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/ and set up a Linux VM.

Comment: @scai It has to be Windows and also windows 2012 r2. And I think when i set it up on a Virtual Machine the performance of the server is bad. Because I need to render the whole river Rhein. The river starts in Switzerland and ends in the Baltic Sea.

Comment: The performance will be lower compared to a native installation. However you will definitely have less problems when staying on Linux.

Comment: But switching to linux is no option :(. This is why I ask here the question. @scai

Answer (score 1):

On Windows it won't be straightforward, but you're not the first person to have tried.  I'm not aware of a "soup to nuts" set of instructions, but I'd start reading [here](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/54208/how-to-serve-osm-mapnik-tiles-on-windows-with-apache-for-leafletjs).  That's an OSM help question about tile serving on windows, and the links from that and the [other questions](https://help.openstreetmap.org/users/13229/koles500) that that user asked are the most comprehensive list that I'm aware of.